# Make phone numbers on the site clickable

Tags: html, reactjs

Im new to react and im faced with a problem where I have to develop a functionality that would make every phone number clickable (put it in the
`<a href="tel:SOME_PHONE_NUMBER">SOME_PHONE_NUMBER</a>` element). Is there a way to achieve this? Can I scan whole site's visible text every time its refreshed to look for them? The site im working on is a call center management service so there is a lot of non-static text (messages from client's etc.) so it would be hard to introduce this functionality only to specific components, and even then im not sure how that could be done.

Comment: You can scan your variables. What are the variables (arrays?) that can contain the phone numbers?